# Error: cannot override "chainId","data","hash","v","r","s","confirmations","wait"

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethers.js

i want to send money to a function but get this error.
i using ethers.js

script:

```
**const {ethers} = require('hardhat');
const abi = require('../data/abi/test.json')
const provider = new ethers.Wallet(   
    "7c4439d4b2367bf58f612c3178b75bbd23a0ad7819dc4f9c1e10222f28e12280",
    ethers.getDefaultProvider("https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/LotkPgb_JVDypKN906IO0mkqaI5jG9GA"));                 
    
const contractAddress = '0x3baec270973DDB17A46315a9E8348b391afa8041'
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress ,abi ,provider )
  
async function wallet() {
 
   
    const options = await provider.sendTransaction({
         value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.11"),
        gasLimit: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 800000000
    })
       
                                    
    const callFunction = await contract.sendMoney(options)
    console.log('tx is:',callFunction)
    const balance = await contract.getBalance()
    console.log("Balance:",(await ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)))
}
wallet()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
  });**
```

full error:

```
Error: cannot override "chainId","data","hash","v","r","s","confirmations","wait" (operation="overrides", overrides=["chainId","data","hash","v","r","s","confirmations","wait"], code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, never publish online your private key or your node API key.

I checked your contract on rinkeby but it's not verified, so I can't tell what input data is the contract accepting.

But I think you will find a solution to your issue by just looking at an example like this one:

https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/461#issuecomment-474470663

I would change the options const to:

```
const options = {
       value:ethers.utils.parseEther("0.11"),
       gasLimit: 2100000,
       gasPrice: ethers.utils.formatUnits(800000000, "gwei")
    }
```